# Access iPhone photo library using Kivy

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I'm using their normal open file program to open the file browser.

I'm using

```
<LoadDialog>:
size: '300dp', '300dp'
title: filechooser.path
choosen_file: None
BoxLayout:

    pos: root.pos
    orientation: "vertical"
    FileChooserIconView:
        id: filechooser
        path: os.path.expanduser('/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Sync/')
```

I'm trying to access the photo library of iOS.

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with Kivy alone yet. But you can try to access Camera to take pictures, at least I think camera is accessible on iOS.